# Cannot get outerHTML/value of a dynamically added textarea

Tags: javascript, html

This fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xa9m49zy/ demonstrates that you can get the outerHTML (with the text area value) of a textarea that is in the DOM when it renders, but when the textarea is dynamically added to the DOM, the outerHTML doesn't contain the text area value. It doesn't work in Firefox and Chrome but it *does* work in IE and Edge.

HTML:

```
<textarea id="abc">
  Test
</textarea>
```

JS:

```
console.log($("#abc").get(0).outerHTML); //returns everything as expected
$("<textarea id='xyz'></textarea>").val("Test 2").appendTo("body");
console.log($("#xyz").get(0).outerHTML); //only shows <textarea></textarea> in non-MS browsers
```

What is going on here? Is this a bug in Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: The "value" property of a `<textarea>` is initialized by the content of the element, but it's not the same thing as the content. In your second example, you're directly setting the "value" property of the DOM node so there simply is no element content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the **value** of the second `textarea` using `.val()`, but `outerHTML` does not retrieve values, it retrieves an element and the **content** of that element.

`textarea` elements get their value from their **content**.

> If you set the **content** for the second `textarea` using the
>   `.text()` method, it works.

```js
alert($("#abc").get(0).outerHTML); //returns everything as expected
$("<textarea id='xyz'></textarea>").text("Test 2").appendTo("body");
alert($("#xyz").get(0).outerHTML); //only shows <textarea></textarea> in non-MS browser
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="abc">
  Test
</textarea>
```

Comment: Makes sense. It's interesting that IE it works as expected. Or maybe that's NOT as expected... :)

Comment: You should never be surprised when IE does things (good or bad) differently from others. I like to develop/test in Chrome as it is very standards compliant.  Don't forget to mark as the answer!

Comment: It's surprising that EDGE works that way though. It's pretty standards compliant...