# $(element).val('newvalue') Is Not Reflected in element.outerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to see the `value` attribute of `input` elements when using `element.outerHTML`.  Problem is with all input types; example HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="copy-paste-textarea" />
```

Example JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#copy-paste-textarea').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log("Text area's outerHTML???" + this.outerHTML + "|");
        // Output: <input id="copy-paste-textarea" type="text">

    $(this).val('hello!');
    $(this).addClass('world!');

    console.log("Text area's outerHTML???" + this.outerHTML + "|");
        // Output: <input id="copy-paste-textarea" class="world!" type="text">
});
</script>
```

When I run this code above, I see that the change from addClass() is reflected in this.outerHTML, but the change of val() is not.  BUT -- I see that the field is indeed actually being populated with the values.  I want output to be this:

```
// Output: <input id="copy-paste-textarea" value="hello!" class="world!" type="text">
```

The html() function produces the same results.  I would like a solution that works on any input type (select, textarea, etc.).

Similar answer here will only work on textareas: [Cannot get outerHTML/value of a dynamically added textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017974/cannot-get-outerhtml-value-of-a-dynamically-added-textarea)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because elements have "properties", which store dynamic information only in memory as expressed by the JavaScript DOM object and they also have "attributes" where the element's actual markup is recorded in memory and is accessible via the HTML parser.

- JQuery's `.val()` method writes data to an in-memory only property.
- To get what you want, you must set the `value` ***attribute*** using
  JQuery's **[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** method.

The subtle, but important difference between properties and attributes is what contributes to the confusion between JQuery's **[`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** and `.attr()` methods.

```js
$('#copy-paste-textarea').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log("input field's outerHTML???" + this.outerHTML + "|");

    // You must set the attribute for it to be picked up in the HTML
    $(this).attr("value", "hello!");
    $(this).addClass('world!');

    console.log("input field's outerHTML???" + this.outerHTML + "|");
});

// For a textarea, you need to get the content of the tags with .text()
$('textarea').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log("Text area's outerHTML???" + this.outerHTML + "|");

    // You must set the attribute for it to be picked up in the HTML
    $(this).text("value", "hello!");
    $(this).addClass('world');
    console.log("Text area's outerHTML???" + this.outerHTML + "|");
});
```

```css
.world {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="copy-paste-textarea">

<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!  I thought all JQuery events were relatively scheduled at the same time, but I guess not.  Thanks!

Comment: @HoldOffHunger We're not talking about events here. It's about updating the JavaScript representation of the object or the DOM object itself.

Comment: Hrm....Solution does not work on textareas.  RE: Events, I was curious why addClass() had no problem with updating the DOM.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger That's because for `textarea` elements, the value is actually the content that is between the opening `<textarea>` and closing `</textarea>` tags. For that, you would use the `.text()` method on the textarea to get that content.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Again, `.addClass()` isn't an event. But, it does update the `class` attribute of the element. I have updated my answer to show a `textarea` and to show that `.addClass()` does update the `class` attribute of the element.